# Open file local to function file in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, filepath

I'm trying to get a MATLAB project work under Octave.  The project's layout looks like this:

```
/myproject/funcs/f1.m
                /data.csv
          /examples/test.m
```

I want to run the routine `test.m`, which makes use of the function `f1`. Inside `f1.m`, there's a call to open the data file:

```
[...]
data = dlmread('data.csv'); % Read the csv file
[...]
```

When I'm inside the `examples` directory, this fails:

```
error: dlmread: unable to open file 'data.csv'
```

So I guess what I'm looking for is some way to tell Octave that the file `data.csv` *is in the same directory as the function definition trying to open it*. This solution should be MATLAB-compatible, so I can contribute the changes necessary to make it work under Octave back to the project.

**What I already tried:**

1. `data = dlmread('./data.csv');` `->` the same error as before

Comment: I don’t have Octave but in Matlab, if you add `myproject/funcs` to the path via `addpath`, then if Matlab’s current path is `myproject/examples/` then `dlmread('data.csv')` works. That is, in Matlab, `dlmread` seems to search all entries in its path for single files. (Note that `dlmread('./data.csv')` does not work. For `dlmread` to search Matlab path, the file string seems to need to be a naked file.)

Comment: you can print the current working directory with `pwd`. I suggest adding your "funcs" directory with addpath and use relative filenames to open your data. For example from test.m use `dlmread ("../funcs/data.csv")`

Comment: @Andy as I wrote, the dlmread is being called from the files inside the funcs dir, so your comment doesn't help me, unfortunately.

Comment: @andreas-h: You wrote you are calling f1 from the eaxmples directory and not from funcs. It doesn't matter where the script for f1 is stored, all operations with relative paths are from `pwd`. You can make a dirty hack and use `mfilename ("fullpath")` and `fileparts` in f1.m do get the absolute filename of data.csv. But I would consider this as bad practise and you should really give relatives path to data.csv as I wrote in the previous comment.

Comment: @Andy Thanks, I'lll look into `mfilename` and `fileparts`. I know it's ugly and a dirty hack. But this project has the data files and the functions to read these data both in the same folder `funcs`, them `dlmread` is called from `f1`. If I would follow your advice to use relative paths in `f1`, then the whole thing would only work when called from `examples` folder, not from `examples/specialexamples`. Of course the clean way to do this would be to have a configuration file specifying the absolute path to the data directory, but that's too big a change to introduce into the project right now.

Comment: why not just `cd` to the function directory in your script right before calling the function, and `cd` back to your script directory immediately after?